# Cut path to first four directories

Tags: directory, path, string, cut

I have several projects where I have to use the same command.
The projects always are in

```
/home/[username]/public_html/[prjectname]/
```

I'd like to run this command from every directory of my projects, so I need to know my project-base.
I tried `${path:0:20}`, but of cause the string length of the user and projectname varies.
I just need to know the **first four parts of the path**.

Comment: You already mention `cut`. Did you read the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already mention `cut`. You just set the delimiter to `/`. The somewhat unintuitive part is that you need fields 1-5, because the part before the first `/` is also counted as an (empty) field.

```
echo /1/2/3/4/5/6/7 | cut -d/ -f1-5
```

Result is

```
/1/2/3/4
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the `zsh` shell, if `$var` is `/1/2/3/4/5/6`, `${var:h1}` is `/`, `${var:h2}` is `/1`, `${var:h3}` is `/1/2` and so on (`h` for *head*, same as is `csh`/`vim`; while the numeric suffix is a `zsh` extension)

So here, to get `/home/user/public_html/projectX` out of `file=/home/user/public_html/projectX/a/b`, it would just be

```
dir=${file:h5}
```

To loop over all the directories that match `/home/*/public_html/*`, that would just be:

```
for dir in /home/*/public_html/*(N/); do
  something with $dir
done
```

(replace `(N/)` with `(N-/)` to also include symlinks to directories; in any case the first `*` will also match symlinks to directories above).

That `(N/)` is a [*glob qualifier*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), a feature specific to `zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider (double) "parameter expansion: Remove matching prefix/suffix pattern":

```
$ path=/home/[username]/public_html/[prjectname]/abc/xyz
$ echo "${path%"${path#/*/*/*/*/}"}"
/home/[username]/public_html/[prjectname]/
```

No external command needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 find /path/to/dir -mindepth 4 -type d | cut -d"/" -f -5 | sort -u
```

- `type -d` will print only directories.
- `mindepth` will print the directories which have minimum 4 subdirectories.
- `-d"/"` use `/` as delimiter to cut
- `-f -5` cut the everything from the fifth column
- `sort -u` will print sorted unique folder paths.